# Maximum Likelihood with two different PDFs

Tags: stochastic-processes, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

I have a time series of discrete observations $X_s$. In total there are N observations. I have some assumption about the underlying data-generating process (it is a Markov process) and thus I know the density of the model $f(X_{s+1}|X_s,\theta)$ for model parameters $\theta$. Actually, I assume that there are two different processes with different parameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ such I have the  densities $f(X_{s+1}|X_s,\theta_1)$ and $f(X_{s+1}|X_s,\theta_2)$. I assume that both processes take turns such that in some periods, the first process generates the data and in other periods the second one does it (I have concrete assumptions about when this should happen; sometimes a direct alternation is possible). I want to estimate the parameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ via maximum likelihood.

My idea therefore is:
$$ \max \sum_{s=1}^{i=N} \log f(X_{s+1}|X_s,\theta) = \max \left[\sum_{i \in Q_1} \log f(X_{i+1}|X_i,\theta_1) + \sum_{i \in Q_2} \log f(X_{j+1}|X_j,\theta_2)\right]$$

where $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are disjunct subsets of {1,...,N}. To get the parameters, I now maximize $$\max \sum_{i \in Q_1} \log f(X_{i+1}|X_i,\theta_1)$$ and $$\max \sum_{j \in Q_2} \log f(X_{j+1}|X_j,\theta_2)$$ separately such that I obtain $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. Is my proceeding sensible and mathematically correct? Or do I harm some preconditions? Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: So in effect your new parameter space includes both $\theta$ values and the $Q$ sets?

Comment: As I see it, yes!

Comment: I think there is a risk of overfitting the data by switching between the $\theta$ values too often.  Another approach would be to build the switching into a more complicated single model with two parameters $(\theta_1,\theta_2).$

Comment: Is the behavior quite different between each of the $\theta$ cases? If not it seems from my chemistry background that you will have a serious difficulty distinguishing between what are essentially interlaced samples from distinct populations (a systemic annoyance in practical chromatography).