# Markov Chain and Maximum Likelihood: Neglecting observations

Tags: probability, markov-chains, maximum-likelihood

Let $ \{ X_i \}_{i=1}^{50}$ be a path of the markov chain.

The probability of observing the path then reads as

\begin{align} 
P_{\theta}(X_1, ..., X_{50}) &= P_{\theta}(X_{50} | X_{49}, ..., X_1) \cdot P_{\theta}(X_1, ..., X_{49}) \\
&= P_{\theta}(X_{50} | X_{49}) \cdot P_{\theta}(X_1, ..., X_{49}) \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{50} P_{\theta}(X_i | X_{i-1} )
\end{align}

However, I am not interested in the probability of observing the whole path, but in observing $\{X_2, X_{25}, X_{50}\}$, meaning I want to neglect some observations.

My intuition is:

\begin{align} 
P_{\theta}(X_2, X_{25}, X_{50}) &= P_{\theta}(X_2 | X_{1}) \cdot P_{\theta}(X_{25} | X_{24}, ..., X_1) \cdot P_{\theta}(X_{50} | X_{49}, ..., X_1)\\
&= P_{\theta}(X_2 | X_{1}) \cdot P_{\theta}(X_{25} | X_{24}) \cdot P_{\theta}(X_{50} | X_{49})
\end{align}

Can I do it like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. One way is
\begin{align}
P(X_2, X_{25}, X_{50}) &=
P(X_2) \cdot P(X_{25} \mid X_2) \cdot P(X_{50} \mid X_{25}, X_2)
\\
&= P(X_2) \cdot P(X_{25} \mid X_2) \cdot P(X_{50} \mid X_{25}),
\end{align}
where the first equality holds for any joint distribution (not necessarily Markov chain), and the second line uses the Markov chain memoryless property.

Alternatively, you can write it as
\begin{align}
P(X_2,X_{25}, X_{50})
&= \sum_{X_i : i \notin\{2,25,50\}} P(X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots,X_{25},\ldots,X_{49}, X_{50})
\\
&= \sum_{X_i : i \notin\{2,25,50\}} 
P(X_1) \prod_{j=2}^{50} P(X_j \mid X_{j-1}),
\end{align}
where the sum is actually $47$ sums, one for each variable $X_i$ over all the values it can take.

Comment: Thank you. Actually this is my original problem, that I need to solve: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358436/maximum-likelihood-with-two-different-pdfs?noredirect=1#comment4867538_2358436. Could you also help me with this?